# segmenting a model in threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js

say you have a simple [raycaster](http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/#webgl_octree_raycasting). When you mouse over, the model will light up.

However, in this implementation, this model would be broken into parts, which would be parts of the model but still their own separate "models". For example, say your model happened to be a car. When you mouse over the hood, it lights up. When you mouse over the door, it lights up, etc.
I did not find any such instance of what I was speaking of in the threejs examples.

is there a way to break a full .obj model into several, individual but connected, models in three.js?

Answer (score 1):

I have been working with threejs for quite a time but I do not think that this is possible, at least not with threejs itself (maybe WebGL has some tools which would help you to achieve this, but still, if it is a complex model such as car, the result would still be pretty terrible). But there are several workarounds.

1. In treejs, create your model from multiple smaller ones. For simple objects this is possible (example: instead of sphere, create two hemispheres and place them next to each other).
2. Instead of using raycaster, use point light. This will cast the light on the area not the object, therefore if you target one big object, you will end up lighting up only the part of the object, based on the intensity and distance of the point light.
3. If you have complex model such as car. Load it with some 3D modelling program (Blender, ...) and break it into smaller ones and then save each of them separatelly. And in your threejs code, load each one separatelly and position them the way it will look like single object. (I guess this is the only reasonable way in this case)